Google Cloud Run - Random 504 Http Errors
We're currently running a Java 11 application on Cloud Run with Jetty 10 and have encountered an unusual issue. While the service generally operates smoothly, we've noticed that a small fraction of POST requests, approximately 1,000 out of 3,000,000 processed in the last month, fail mysteriously. These failed requests result in either a 503 malformed response or a 504 gateway timeout HTTP error, with the majority being 504 errors. Strangely, these requests seem to remain in an idle state without being picked up by the instance for execution. Eventually, they end up executing successfully on a different instance. Moreover, these failed requests share the same instanceID (there are some successful requests for this instance among the failed ones which is even more bizarre).
Regarding the 503 malformed response errors, we've consulted Google's troubleshooting documentation and ruled out memory issues and application-level timeouts. Despite our investigation, we haven't identified any downstream network bottlenecks, and our request rate remains well below Google's specified limits at an average of 15 requests per second.
For the 504 gateway timeout errors, the message indicates that the request has reached the maximum request timeout, yet it appears that these requests never actually reach the instance, as they don't produce any logs indicating execution.
Below are some related screenshots.


To address these issues, we've taken several steps:

Configured readiness and liveness probes to determine instance health, which have generally functioned well. In one "faulty" instance, the liveness probe detected an issue after one hour, resulting in the termination of this instance.
Monitored CPU and memory utilization, both of which appear healthy, with CPU consistently under 50% and no occurrences of out-of-memory errors.
Ensured proper closure of resources, such as Google Cloud file storage and Redis client connections, to prevent resource leaks.
Confirmed compliance with Google Cloud API quotas, ensuring that we're not hitting any limits.

Cloud Run Configuration
CPU allocation: CPU is always allocated.
Startup CPU boost: Enabled
Concurrency: 80
Request timeout: 1800 seconds
Execution environment: Second generation
Autoscaling: Enabled 
Min instances: 12
Max instances: 100
CPU Limit: 4
Memory Limit: 8GB
Session Affinity: Enabled
HTTP2: Disabled

Furthermore, we utilize a VPC connector to route traffic only to private IPs, and we remain within all specified thresholds.
We would really appreciate any insights you might have into what might be causing these issues.
Best regards.

Did you figure it out yet? We started experiencing 504 errors in one of our cloud run services 2 months ago, without making any changes at our part. We cannot se any issue with CPU or memory either, and it always happens with the one instance that is configured with a VPC connector. However, when the 504 first start, they don't stop until we redeploy our application.

@SteffenStenersen facing similar issues today. please share if any root causes found. thanks!

I'm still experiencing (randomly) the same issue, and it's quite frustrating since Google support hasn't been very helpful. If you manage to find a solution, please keep me in the loop.

Since you mentioned that you already tried the troubleshooting steps to resolve both 503 and 504 errors, I would also suggest to check this documentation on Cloud Run responds with an HTTP 504 Gateway timeout error.
Similarly, this is also related to error 503 which is caused by an out of memory error.
One of the suggestions would be deploying a new Cloud Run application to check whether this issue would reoccur.
I would also suggest filing a bug through the Google Cloud issue tracker so that Google Cloud engineers could take a look at this, however this doesn't have a specific ETA but you can keep track of the process once the ticket has been created.

Thank you for the reply Robert. Regrettably, I've found Google support to be subpar. I submitted a support ticket, but the response seemed largely automated. We also have a Spring Boot Cloud Run application running smoothly without encountering this issue, despite utilizing similar functionalities such as Datastore, Redis, and Cloud Storage. "Luckily", I haven't experienced the issue in the past few days. During this time, we made some enhancements to the code, such as closing certain file streams that were left open and implementing "try with resources" in places where it was missing.
